# align 3 divs inline

Tags: css, html

i am trying to align 3 divs inline with each other

i have

```
#header {
    width:100%;
    height:160px;
}
```

as the main container so the container fits the width of the page (100%)

then

```
.header-left {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
.logo {
    width:409px; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.header-right {
    width:33%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

for the 3 divs in the container.

I need the .logo div in the centre of the page and in between the other 2 divs, so then the 2 other divs either side of the logo div.

the logo div needs to be 409px as thats the width of the logo.

for some reason it is just all displaying to the left and i cannot work out why

Comment: please create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: can you provide the html ?

Comment: fiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/R65fA/

Comment: In this context, what happen if 409px is more than 34% of total width ? it breaks. --> http://jsfiddle.net/C8amN/

Comment: aha i see - ok if the left and right elements are 350px max?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is possible if you arrange the header HTML as follows:

```
<header class="ex1">
    <div class="header-left">the left stuff </div>
    <div class="header-right">the right stuff</div>
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://placehold.it/409x138" ></div>
</header>
```

and apply the following CSS:

```
header {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
}
.ex1 .header-left {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
}
.ex1 .logo {
    width: 409px; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.ex1 .logo img {
    display: block;
}
.ex1 .header-right {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: right;
}
```

Basically, you float the left header element to the left, the right element to the right,
and keep the logo element centered in the normal box flow.

Set the `min-width` to allow for a fixed with logo/banner image.

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Esst8/

Comment: I was not sure how you wanted the left/right elements to work.  There are many ways of doing this depending on your layout specifications.  Please remember to up vote all relevant solutions and accept one as appropriate.  Good luck!

Comment: what if `logo` div is longer than left and right and i would like left and right to match the height property?

Comment: @bonez I am not sure what you mean. Did you mean if the logo div is taller than either the left and right `div`'s?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, what happen if 409px is more than 34% of total width ? it breaks.

Think about rewriting your html, it won't work this way.

Answer (score 1):

### Restructure and use `Float`

To get what you want, the best thing to do is restructure your HTML and make sure you set a `min-width` on the `body`. Something like this ([as seen in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R65fA/11/)):

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
        <div class="header-left">LEFT</div>
      <div class="header-right">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo" width="409" height="138" /></div>
</div>
```

**Essential CSS**

```
body {
    min-width: 600px; /* some minimum greater than 409px */
}

.header-left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    margin-right: -204.5px;
    border-right: 204.5px solid transprent;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logo {
    width:409px; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.header-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -204.5px;
    border-left: 204.5px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Update:** to keep it functioning "on-center," you have to account for the larger of the two side pieces in your `min-width` setting. So if you are putting some fixed width element on each side, then you need to calculate your `min-width` based on the larger of those two side elements by this formula:

> ((Larger side piece px) x 2) + 409px Logo = Minimum width

Don't forget to account for borders, etc. as needed in sizing that.

Comment: Nice application of CSS3 rules for box-sizing.

Comment: Try adding an image for the fun of it.... <img src="http://placehold.it/409x138" />

Comment: I have just tried with the same HTML but adding an image and its gone all over the place? any ideas?

<div id="header">
  <div class="header-left"><img src="images/phone_icon.png" width="323" height="58" /></div>
  <div class="header-right">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo" width="409" height="138" /></div>
 </div>

Comment: @charliejsford: yes, you are dealing with another image that is `323px` wide, so you need to make sure your `min-width` is enough to allow for a `323px` image beside your `409px` logo (so `1055px` for `min-width`). Otherwise, the logo is going to shift down (and perhaps the right element as well in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: inline` instead of `display: inline-block` for your div

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R65fA/1/

I just read @Milche Patern answer and notice that you use both percentage and fixed width for your child element. It's really bad idea. You better rewrite to make it standard.

Comment: aha yes! how about making it all centre of the header container?

Answer (score 0):

```
#header{ width:100%}
.header-left {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
.logo {
    width:34%; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px 0px 0px;
    float:left; height:138px;
}
.header-right {
    width:33%;
    float:left;
}
.clr{ clear:both;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header">
     <div class="header-left">LEFT</div>
     <div class="header-right">RIGHT</div>
     <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo" width="409" height="138" /></div>
     <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```