# Displaying 3 inline divs

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS / HTML code:

```
.ex1 .box-left {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    float: left;
    margin:10px 0 0 70px;
}
.ex1 .box-middle {
    width: 33%; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px auto 0 auto;
}
.ex1 .box-right {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    float: right;
    margin:10px 70px 0 0;
}

<div class="ex1">
        <div class="box-left">text goes here</div>
        <div class="box-right">text goes here</div>
        <div class="box-middle">text goes here</div>
    </div>
```

I need them to show all next to each other with the same margin in between each one and in the centre of the page but then when the window is made smaller, if they are not going to fit they should start displaying below each other

any ideas what i can do?

Comment: A few of us helped you on this issue yesterday in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665312/align-3-divs-inline  If you are going to use my fiddle in a new question, accept my answer and up vote it.

Comment: 21 questions asked, 5 answers awarded. Not good stats.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is [`Responsive Web Design`](http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/)

see one more [useful resource](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Media Queries" - how to use! [check this](http://stackcomplete.com/media-queries-for-adaptive-to-responsive-websites/) also [this](http://stackcomplete.com/responsive-web-design-tutorial/)

You can use styles for all sizes, its like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
//your styles for this resolution 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
//your styles for this resolution 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
//your styles for this resolution 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
//your styles for this resolution 
}
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
//your styles for this resolution 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First u give fix to main div and after inside all 3 div give a float.

```
<div class="ex1">
        <div class="box-left">text goes here</div>
        <div class="box-right">text goes here</div>
        <div class="box-middle">text goes here</div>
<div style="float:none; clear:both;"
    </div>

.ex1 {width:960px; margin:0 auto;}
.ex1 .box-left {
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    float: left;
    margin:10px 0 0 70px;
}
.ex1 .box-middle {
    width: 33%; /* width of the logo */
    margin:10px 0 ;
float:left;
}
.ex1 .box-right {
    width: 33%;
    max-width: 190px;
    float: right;
    margin:10px 70px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people would frown on this solution for using `text-align` to center content other than text, but this seems to do what you're asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/3hfPZ/

Here's the markup:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="box red"></div>
    <div class="box blue"></div>
    <div class="box yellow"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
#main { margin: auto; text-align: center; }
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
```

The colors and sizes I picked are arbitrary, just to make it clear what's happening with the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the float properties since you had apply display:inline-block.

This is the simplest method you could find.

Here's the markup:

> ```
> <div class="globalcontainer">
>     <div class="ex1">
>     <div class="ex-box">Left</div>
>     <div class="ex-box">Middle</div>
>     <div class="ex-box">Right</div>
>     </div>
> </div>
> ```

Here's the CSS:

```
.globalcontainer {width:100%; height:auto; overflow:auto; background-color:#333;}
.ex1 { text-align:center; margin:0 auto;}
.ex-box{
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:100px;
    max-width: 190px;
    margin:10px 5px;
    background-color:#f90;
}
```

This code will meet your requirement of centering all the div with same margin when on full browser and after resize they will appear vertically downwards with their specific margin.

Since middle is your logo, just style another class and add whatever you need to beautify it!